# how can I put a class in JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

```
tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.addTab( "Page 1", class1);
tabbedPane.addTab( "Page 2", class2);
tabbedPane.addTab( "Page 3", class3);
topPanel.add( tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
```

can i put 3 classes here? How?

Comment: Huh? Could you expand on your issue a little bit more please?

Comment: I would like to put different classes in JTabbedPane. is that possible?

Comment: [addTab String, Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) allows you to add any class that extends [component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html)

Comment: Do you mean different classes extending `Component`? You can't add a class itself, but you can an add instance of a class extending `Component`.

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a read through [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

You can only instance of classes that extend from `Component`, so assuming your three classes extend from `Component`, you shouldn't have any issues